# Store each file in a sublist based on subfolder

Tags: python, for-loop

There is a `list_1` which has paths of many subfolders.

```
list_1
```

which gives:

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00001\\ground_truth.json',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00002\\ground_truth.json',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\problem00003\\ground_truth.json']
```

**Purpose**

In `gt2` list there should be a sublist for the `json` file from `problem1`. Then another sublist for the json from `problem2` and so on.

The attempted code below stores all the json files in the `gt2` list.

```
gt2=[]
for k in list_1:
    with open(k, 'r') as f:
        gt = {}
        for i in json.load(f)['ground_truth']:
            gt[i['unknown-text']] = i['true-author']
        gt2.append(gt)
```

The end result should be: inside the `gt2` list to have 3 sublists:

one for the file from `problem1`,

another from `problem2` and

another from `problem3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the list is sorted, use `enumerate` over `list_1` & the make `gt2` as dict to store the json data.

```
gt2 = {}

for k, v in enumerate(list_1):
    gt = {}
    with open(v, 'r') as f:
        for i in json.load(f):
            gt[i['unknown-text']] = i['true-author']

    gt2[f'problem{k + 1}'] = gt

# access values of dict here
print(gt2['problem1'])
```

**Edit**

```
gt2 = []

for fi in list_1:
    with open(fi, 'r') as f:
        gt2.append([
            {i['unknown-text']: i['true-author']} for i in json.load(f)
        ])
```

Comment: it appears to take only problem0?

Comment: use `enumerate(list_1, 1)`, now `k` starts at 1

Comment: how to make it in a list though? I tried to turn gt2 to a list but it doesn't work.